# How do I store types in a dictionary?

Tags: delphi, generics

I want to create a dictionary of type against instance in Delphi.

If I declare the following:

```
m_things: TDictionary<TClass, TThing>;
```

that gets me dictionary of *any* type against an instance of TThing. How do I restrict the type to be an instance of TThing or derived classes? I'd like to do:

```
m_things: TDictionary<class of TThing, TThing>;
```

but I get the following error:

```
[dcc32 Error] collector.pas(13): E2058 Class, interface and object types only allowed in type section
```

I also tried:

```
m_abstract: TDictionary<T: TThing, TThing>;
```

but then I get this error:

```
[dcc32 Error] collector.pas(13): E2003 Undeclared identifier: 'T'
```

I'm not clear if this is possible, and what the syntax might be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to declare a type to represent the [metaclass](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Class_References) using the `class of` syntax. Like this:

```
type
  TThingClass = class of TThing;
....
var
  m_things: TDictionary<TThingClass, TThing>;
```

Comment: perhaps Delphi compiler could declare a type similar to generic arrays, `TClass<T> = class of T`

Comment: @Arioch'The That's a sweet idea, it would be good if the compiler supported it.

Comment: You could post that as a request at Quality Portal and let it gather votes, post a link to it here.  Class of is not the ohly thing you might need to define a type for before using, others include the pointer `^` and address-of `@` operators, procedure and procedure of object types (callbacks), and more.

Comment: class of TThing as a seperate type was what I found also.